# How to create Windows Explorer large thumbnail style list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluid-layout

My goal is to create item list that would behave like Windows Explorer Large Thumbnail mode, here is an example:

[image]

and here is another picture showing the fluidness when re-sizing the window:

[image]

So I saw this and thought to myself, oh that is easy, I'll just set elements to take up a specific amount of space like `20%` and set min height and width and I got this:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/ZvfrL/)
[image]

But as you guessed `width: 20%` stays that way and the result looks like this:

[image]

which in my case is far from ideal, because now I need to use from **`[1]`** to **`[how many items I want to limit per screen width]`** media queries that will tell items to take a different `%` relative to container.

I want to know is there a smart way to achieve this without writing 15 media queries or a really minimal JavaScript implementation that will handle this for me?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3, you can use the box-sizing attribute and set it to "border-box".  Code via [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

When you set to border-box, the width you set on your elements (the 20%) will include the padding and border for the elements so 20% will actually be 20%.  By default, with `box-sizing: content-box`, your items will be 20% + padding + width (greater than 20% each) and reflow to the next line sooner than you expected.  You can stick with the default box-sizing if you like, but you'll need to adjust your percentages to take into account the padding and border you've specified for the elements.

Check [browser support on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing).

You could also check into using [Flexboxes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but I don't think that's necessary for your use case and will further limit the browsers you can support.

Comment: I can't seem to make it work http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/ZvfrL/1/ , could you provide an example?

Comment: Try this update: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvfrL/5/ -- main change is removing the max-width on .box-container because that completely breaks what you're trying to do with setting its width to 20%.  You should also have global selector for `box-sizing` as the first thing in the CSS as it applies to all elements.  (Not normally something you want to do, but it makes sense and works well for `box-sizing`.)

Comment: Are you using a specific browser, I'm using Chrome and those boxes do not expand like they do in Windows Explorer images.